# How to join multiple rows from same table in single row

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query. also please find following  for table schema

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36d20/14

```
SELECT
  ca1.*,
  ca2.*
FROM Contact_Address AS ca1
  JOIN Contact_Address AS ca2
    ON ca1.ca_contact_id = ca2.ca_contact_id
WHERE ca1.ca_contact_id = 1
    AND ca1.ca_type = 'PRI'
    AND ca2.ca_type = 'SEC'
```

I have to combine two rows which are contained in same table into single row.they contain type 'PRI','SEC'.But the condition is that for one user it will contain both rows and for another it will contain only one.

Please help,
thanks

Comment: @PeterLang OP needs to return resultset with one row with columns of `ca1` + `ca2`. "will contain only one" looks like `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`.

Comment: it was above which is current requirement ... it will contain only one i mean that either of the two will present.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  ca1.ca_contact_id as ci1,ca1.ca_type as type1,
  ca2.ca_contact_id as ci2, ca2.ca_type as type2
FROM Contact_Address AS ca1
  JOIN Contact_Address AS ca2
    ON ca1.ca_contact_id = ca2.ca_contact_id
WHERE ca1.ca_contact_id = 1
    AND ca1.ca_type = 'PRI'
    AND ca2.ca_type = 'SEC'
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36d20/21)

You have to specify your col names

Comment: no dude this is wrong .Have you seen my query response in http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36d20/14  i wanted just like that.And it will not contain     
`AND ca1.ca_type = 'PRI'
    AND ca2.ca_type = 'SEC'`